# Calculate the number of distincts values of custom field

Tags: html, mysql, css, wordpress

I need to make list of checkboxes  based on number of distinct values of some custom field (Country), for visitors to be able to choose only those post where the field Country is of their interest. (see here: http://goo.gl/0D2QgX).

For now, I have decided to make SQL request like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Countries)
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to modify it or find more effective and proper way for this task.

Thank you.

Comment: The question is very hard to read. Can you at least show the table structure?

Comment: Thank you.  I have simplified it. Please try to read now.

Comment: Still can't make sense of the question. But from the screenshot, it looks like you need some sort of grouping: `SELECT Country, COUNT(*) FROM Countries GROUP BY Country;`

Comment: it should be disctinct. For example 200 post with customfield US and 120 with Canada. So respond should be 2 lines only - US (200) and Canada (120).

Comment: That's exactly what `GROUP BY` is for. I think you're misusing the term "distinct".

Comment: Yes. It works. I have only problem that it give me such array   public 'COUNT(*)' => string '1' (length=1) and when I try to use 'var_dump (request->'COUNT(*)')' it give me error. So I don't know how to echo this variable.

Comment: http://goo.gl/3o3awj - such array. my php code: http://goo.gl/Y1v8Cu and error: http://goo.gl/rDbwEf

Comment: give it an alias, e.g. `COUNT(*) AS cnt`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT myField) FROM Countries`

You should check distinct values of a specific field. So, add the field name you are finding the distinct value of, in place of `myField` and the count of distinct values of that field will be the output of this query.

But note that the count will be excluding `NULL`. Because distinct gives you the different values and `null` is not a value, it is absence of any value.